# VSCode : auto unfold a region on cursor move, how to disable this behaviour?

Tags: visual-studio-code

vscode automaticaly unfold region if I get my cursor down on it, it's bothering me and I don't find how to disable this behaviour. Do you know how can I do it ?

Thanks

EDIT:

I add an example, `[]` represent my cursor position

I am on the first line of my function which is fold:

```
myNic[]eFunction() {
}
```

I use the down arrow to move my cursor after the function but it automatically unfold the function and put my cursor on the first line of the function as follow:

```
myNicefunction(){
  // do[]es awesome
  // stuff
  // like print hello world
}
```

Comment: Do you have this setting enabled: `Editor > Unfold On Click After End Of Line`? If so, disable it.  Where is your cursor when it unfolds?

Comment: This settings is correctly disabled. I Edit the post with an example for better understanding

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By any chance are you using the Vim extension?

If so you will likely want to enable `vim.foldfix`:
https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/blob/2d8ce4304a697741950b0fce77b1004458e4e018/src/configuration/iconfiguration.ts#L310

A hack was required because Microsoft did not want to provide an API within 12 months... in 2017:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22276#issuecomment-345259409

Comment: Yes I'm using the vim extension ! Thanks for this solution, I totaly gave up on this ahah

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea why this isn't the default as it was very difficult to track down the issue. :shrug:

Comment: not all heroes wear capes!

Comment: As @PaNaVTEC said: "not all heroes wear capes!".
Thanks so much for this, no idea why this isn't enabled by default.